# CSS Cumulative percentages

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a grid system that doesn't require a lot of classes to be able to be functional.

One way I taught of was to use a coin based system. For example, in Europe we can make the equivalent of any €1 coin, by combining:

1. 2 x .50c,
2. 1x.50c + 2x.20c + 1x.10c,
3. 1x.50c + 1x.20c + 2x.10c, + 2x.05c

You get the idea.

With this in mind I would like to create a set of CSS classes, for example:

1. c1 for 1%
2. c2 for 2%
3. c5 for 5%
4. c10 for 10%
5. c20 for 20%
6. c50 for 50%
7. c100 for 100%

Now lets say someone wanted to have 33%, they would (in theory) get it by combining:
1xc20 + 1xc10 + 1xc2 + 1xc1 = 33%

The potential html might look like (in theory)

```
<div class="c20 c10 c2 c1">
    some text
</div>
```

Now using this people using my theoretical grid system, could potentially create grids of any shape or size with minimal classes, I think the max required would be 5.

**My question:** Is there a way in HTML/CSS to combine classes like this that would allow me to "accumulate" a total width (like in the example above 33%)? Or would I have to make potentially 100 different classes one for each %?

I would be open to using any CSS pre-processors (SCSS/LESS for example), but I'd prefer to know if it's possible in straight HTML/CSS.

However, I would prefer to not resort to JavaScript / jQuery for the same reason (as I think more about it) I don't want to use CSS post-processors.

One last note, the % here is just for simplicity, it could just as easily be any other measurement (px, em, rem etc). For example, if we have a 1000px width we could divide it into 100 parts of 10px each and play with them as needed. Using grids within grids in some way if we wanted to break down the 10px even smaller.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do this using plain CSS, so relevant answers are probably going to use SCSS/LESS.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister - I would be curious to see if such an answer didn't generate 100 different css classes though - one for each %. Cause if it did, it wouldn't be practical if for example it was pixel based on a screen width of 960 or 1200 etc as it would require that number of classes. At least this is my thinking. I could be wrong. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If you need an explicit and hardcoded width value simply use old good vanilla inline HTM styles, e.g.: `<div style="width: 33%">`.

Comment: @seven-phases-max - A simple and precise answer. Very cool. I'm trying to find fault with it but even if I was able to create my various classes, it amounts to the very same thing you just suggested. Which I think, would lead to the same problems, those being the inline styles, or equivalent complex classes, would probably not be a recommended approach. Thanks for this - that really made me think.

Comment: Why not just define `c1`, `c2`, `c3` all the way to `c100`? It would irritate me to have to do maths to figure out how wide my div was going to be.

Comment: @DavidG - This is what I discussed below partypete's answer. I agreed with him that it would defeat the purpose. What if I have a 1200 pixel wide screen, do I then make 1200 classes? I didn't realise how silly I sounded it until then. Another commenter pointed out the inline style width 33% etc, which really made me think that my method would have the same weaknesses as inline styles. It would bloat the html and be hard to maintain. Thanks for your answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you would have to create each one.
eg,

.c20.c10.c2.c1 {width:33%}

But I don't think this system has much merit - What if the user wanted it to be 33% for mobile and 100% for tablet or desktop? Surely bootstraps "col-xs-4 col-lg-12" is a lot simpler.

Comment: I agree, going the way of this suggestion would mean I would have to make potentially thousands of selectors cause I would have to account for every possible combination of every number between 1 and 100. So yup, even if possible, its not really practical. Agreed. This is why I asked if there was a way to total the percentages. Without that, it wouldn't be practical to even consider it. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

No. Not in the way you have in mind. CSS is not a programming language and you are asking it to have functions that accumulate variables and push them into other variables. CSS does not have any of those things. That is not its function.

Comment: This is why I asked if there was potentially a way to do it with SCSS or LESS as they have ways to calculate / generate but I am not sure how as I just started my journey into pre-processors. Thanks for your answer.